# Using D3 Zoomable Tree Map Code as a Template

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[Somewhat related stack overflow question about loading json without http request in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934853/d3-js-loading-json-without-a-http-get)

I am just beginning to learn javascript but I perhaps ambitiously thought that I could take the code from this [very cool zoomable treemap by Mike Bostock](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/), hard code my own json within the file instead of using d3.json, and easily have the tree map reflect my new data. As a practice I have inserted trial json that I know should be formatted correctly, using the method recommended by the above quoted stack overflow question. The replaced part of the code looks like this:

```
var root = {"name": "flare","children": [{"name": "analytics","children": [{"name": "cluster","children": [{"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 10 }]}]}]};

function(root) {

initialize(root);
accumulate(root);
layout(root);
display(root);
```

It originally looked like this, with a closing bracket at the very end of the script that I have removed:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(root) {

  initialize(root);
  accumulate(root);
  layout(root);
  display(root);
```

But when I open the html file in my browser, I just get an empty grey box instead of a treemap. I realize I am making some sort of very basic error, I just can't even begin to figure out what it is. Is my 'template' approach doomed until I learn more about d3/javascript, or is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the complete solution to your problem, but at the least you will need to work with JSON.parse(JSON_STRING_HERE) rather than the string in directly.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the d3.json() method (not sure why I didn't want to use it to begin with) but I will keep json.parse() in mind in the future.