# In Rails, how do I use a JSON object that I want to manipulate with D3 in asset .js.coffee?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js, coffeescript

I am trying to include a D3 graph in my rails project. And I could use some advice on a good strategy.

For starters, to learn how it works, I hard-coded a json object in `assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee`
and wrote the code that generates the d3 graphic. So far so good. The graphic renders good with the static data, so it's not somethting with d3. The question is related to accessing the json data.

So now I would like to store my json in a variable in my controller, so that 
upon click on an ajax link, a new json object is generated and the graph updates with the new data.

As I see in the answer to this question ([Render D3 graph from a string of JSON instead of a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622936/render-d3-graph-from-a-string-of-json-instead-of-a-json-file))
I don't need to use the `d3.json` function since I already have my json object.

Also, this case is different from accessing a static json file stored in the server since the json is generated with the ajax link.

So this is what I have in myController:

```
def identification_item
  @sii = params[:sii_id]
  @fragments = SpectrumIdentificationItem.find(@sii).fragments
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render json: @fragments } 
  end
end
```

I know the action is proccessed as JS, I can see it in the server log, and I check in the Network tab in Chrome's inspector
that a json object is generated as a response with the correct data.

But from here I don't know how to proceed

How do I access this ajax generated json object in my view?

I have tried to access `@fragments` in `assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee` like so:

`jsonFragmentIons = @fragments`

and continue with my working d3 code but @fragments is not accessible that way

Should I keep my D3 working code in `assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee` or should change it to `views/my_controller/my_json_generating_action.js.erb` ?

If I create this js view (`identification_item.js.erb`) I guess I could include the javascript to update the div where my graph is displayed somehow

Or should I create a .json file under `views/my_controller` and then read it with D3.json?

I'm  a bit lost here, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you seen [this project](https://github.com/iblue/d3-rails)?

Comment: Yes I have, I already have d3 for rails installed and running, though the line in my gem file is `gem 'd3js-rails'` instead of `gem "d3-rails"` as stated in the github, I can't remember now where i got that