# d3 piechart from local json variable

Tags: json, d3.js

I am trying to create a donut chart using json from a local variable (rather than an external file) I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934853/d3-js-loading-json-without-a-http-get) but am having a hard time adjusting my code in the same way

In the above example

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
```

was replaced with

```
root = JSON.parse( myjson );
```

which does not fix my problem

Check out the fiddle below where my data is loaded as variable titled myJson. How can I use this data for the donut?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Rename your JSON variable to `data`.
2. Delete the `d3.json` call (but keep the code within it).

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/1/). You also need to append your SVG to "body" and not "#body".

Comment: nice! data is dynamic so what would be the next step to update the pie every time data changes?

Comment: There's a ton of examples for that, e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).