# how to draw a d3 pie chart from a json file

Tags: d3.js, charts, geojson

here is the json file

{

"name": "Packages",

```
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Talks",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "talk_1",
                "size": 722,
                "url": "www.example_1.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "talk_2",
                "size": 722,
                "url": "www.example_2.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "talk_3",
                "size": 722,
                "url": "www.example_3.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

i want to draw a pie chart from the above code. I want to know how to access the nodes. i want to create a pie chart based on the value "size". 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/32te68uv/4/), forked from [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/1/), [found on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716671/d3-piechart-from-local-json-variable), [using Google](http://www.google.com). Your pie chart is here more or less as I understand it, labels and all. This took about 5 minutes of research and almost no background in `d3`. Just saying... did you try at all before you asked?

Knowing little about `d3` but much about Google, I searched for "d3 pie chart" and found http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235.

I then searched for "d3 pie chart json" and found a Stack Overflow answer [d3 piechart from local json variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716671/d3-piechart-from-local-json-variable)  that pointed to this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/fg9MU/1/

Now, if you want it to update dynamically, check this example out. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410

There are really a wealth of resources on Google.

If you need help with your specific case, here's what you need to do at a high level:

1. Define the chart object and how it will look
2. Create function mapping your objects to numbers
3. Connect (1) and (2)

So to spell it out,

```
var dataFromYou = [
    {
        "name": "Talks",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "talk_1",
                "size": 722,
                "url": "www.example_1.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "talk_2",
                "size": 722,
                "url": "www.example_2.com"
            },
            {
                "name": "talk_3",
                "size": 722,
                "url": "www.example_3.com"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var data = dataFromYou[0].children;

var width = 800,
    height = 250,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(radius - 70);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function (d) {
    return d.size;
});



var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

    g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.name);
    });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.size;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. It works great. I am trying to include the jsonfile externally using this function                                         d3.json("MYfile.json", function(error, data).  I searched the google for this example but i am not getting how to access the nodes. Thanks in advance sir your answer helped me a lot

Comment: What do you mean by access the nodes? Can you post what you've done on a fiddle? You can use a URL for the Json.

Comment: {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
                                                                                
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME_2": "East Godavari",  "profit": 326 }},
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NAME_2": "East Godavari",  "profit": 1762 }
]
}                                                                                                                                   This is the content in my jsonfile i.e MYfile.json. i want to plot pie chart on "profit" value. How to access the profit value to plot the pie chart.Thanks for helping me sir

Comment: All you have to do is change the data and change three places, the end of `var pie = `, the part `g.append(path)`, and the very last line. search for `d.size`, `d.data.name`, and `d.data.size`. Change those

Comment: The syntax of the json file has changed, so the code you provided is not working. I followed your instructions but it is not showing the result. Just now made the changes in fiddle. :-(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/venkatkiranpolamuri/92hn5bfb/                                                 i have done modifications as per your instructions but it is not working. fiddle link