# How to load data from an internal JSON array rather than from an external resource / file for a collapsible tree in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I wish to load a JSON data array from within a file to generate a collapsible tree diagram per the [Mike Bostock example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083). The example uses a correctly formatted external JSON file and loads it using the d3.json function.

I wish to be able to load a json array from within the file, which is the result of the generation of a multi-level array from a flay array (per the [example question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847131/generate-multilevel-flare-json-data-format-from-flat-json)).

A [sample file I have stood up on bl.ocks.org / GitHub](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/raw/8273682/) shows both parts of what I am trying to achieve without the crucial part of taking the multi-level JSON data and joining it to the collapsible tree diagram

In short. I declare the following data inside the file;

```
var data = [
     { "name" : "ABC", "parent":"DEF", "relation": "ghi", "depth": 1 },
     { "name" : "DEF", "parent":"null", "relation": "null", "depth": 0 },
     { "name" : "new_name", "parent":"ABC", "relation": "rel", "depth": 2 },
     { "name" : "new_name2", "parent":"ABC", "relation": "foo", "depth": 2 },
     { "name" : "Foo", "parent":"DEF", "relation": "rel", "depth": 2 }
    ];
```

Which is then run through this portion of code...

```
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.name] = node;
    return map;
}, {});

// create the tree array
var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
    // add to parent
    var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
    if (parent) {
        // create child array if it doesn't exist
        (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
            // add node to child array
            .push(node);
    } else {
        // parent is null or missing
        treeData.push(node);
    }
});
```

Which converts the array into multi-level json as follows (it is also pushed to the screen for reference);

```
[
  {
    "name": "DEF",
    "parent": "null",
    "relation": "null",
    "depth": 0,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "ABC",
        "parent": "DEF",
        "relation": "ghi",
        "depth": 1,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "new_name",
            "parent": "ABC",
            "relation": "rel",
            "depth": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "new_name2",
            "parent": "ABC",
            "relation": "foo",
            "depth": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Foo",
        "parent": "DEF",
        "relation": "rel",
        "depth": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But then I have to load the same data from an external file in order to get it into the collapsible tree diagram. The code that does this is as follows;

```
d3.json("example.json", function(error, DEF) {
  root = DEF;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});
```

With the diagram looking like this...

[image]

I'm pretty sure I've just had some sort of mental block that is doing my head in and that this is a simple answer, but it has defeated me for a few hours now.

How do I pass the correctly formatted JSON data from the formatting portion of the code to the diagram part?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I've added a [JSFiddle with the suggested edits from Jesus here (http://jsfiddle.net/LGvha/)](http://jsfiddle.net/LGvha/).

Comment: Hi d3noob, am totally impressed with this. Could you help me with my below question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527019/d3-tree-layout-visualization-inherit-child-with-multiple-parents

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are very close, all you need to do is set the treeData you created as the root of the tree. So instead of loading the JSON data, you would do:

```
// replace this line
// d3.json("/d/4063550/flare.json", function(error, flare) {
root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse);
update(root);
//remove this line
// });
```

Comment: I tried that as one of my many attempts, but I received the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined " after the `root.children.forEach(collapse);` line. I didn't understand the error since a console.log entry at that point indicates that the array `root` exists with `.children` as associative array elements. I thought you had it too. Darn, this is bedeviling me. I think you're right. This is really close to solved, but I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle with the suggested edits at http://jsfiddle.net/LGvha/. Thanks for looking.

Comment: If I log your "root" to the console, I get `[Object, x0: 230, y0: 0]`; the problem is that your data building method is wrapping the root object in an array, so what you really need is `root=treeData[0]` to access the object out from the array.

Comment: Outstanding! That's the ticket! Many thanks Jesus and Amelia. That's a good lesson for me! Have a good new year :-) (P.S I'll edit Jesus's answer to include Amelia's addition for any future searches)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tips/pointers ... I am a total noob in JS and I fail to understand why full code examples are given rather than snippets. In the python community such answers would usually be punished severely.

I do have a full example - I hope this allows someone else to avoid the 2 hours of frustration I have just sloughed my way through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//MyData
  var flareStr='{"name": "flare", "children": [{"name": "analytics", "children": [{"name": "cluster", "children": [{"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938}, {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812}, {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714}, {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}]}, {"name": "graph", "children": [{"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534}, {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731}, {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840}, {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914}, {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}]}, {"name": "optimization", "children": [{"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}]}]}, {"name": "animate", "children": [{"name": "Easing", "size": 17010}, {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842}, {"name": "interpolate", "children": [{"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983}, {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047}, {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375}, {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746}, {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202}, {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382}, {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629}, {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675}, {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}]}, {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041}, {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176}, {"name": "Pause", "size": 449}, {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593}, {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534}, {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201}, {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975}, {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116}, {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}]}, {"name": "data", "children": [{"name": "converters", "children": [{"name": "Converters", "size": 721}, {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294}, {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800}, {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314}, {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}]}, {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759}, {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165}, {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586}, {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331}, {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772}, {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}]}, {"name": "display", "children": [{"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833}, {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732}, {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623}, {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}]}, {"name": "flex", "children": [{"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}]}, {"name": "physics", "children": [{"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082}, {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336}, {"name": "IForce", "size": 319}, {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498}, {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822}, {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983}, {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213}, {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}]}, {"name": "query", "children": [{"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616}, {"name": "And", "size": 1027}, {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891}, {"name": "Average", "size": 891}, {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893}, {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103}, {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677}, {"name": "Count", "size": 781}, {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141}, {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933}, {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130}, {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617}, {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240}, {"name": "If", "size": 2732}, {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039}, {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214}, {"name": "Match", "size": 3748}, {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843}, {"name": "methods", "children": [{"name": "add", "size": 593}, {"name": "and", "size": 330}, {"name": "average", "size": 287}, {"name": "count", "size": 277}, {"name": "distinct", "size": 292}, {"name": "div", "size": 595}, {"name": "eq", "size": 594}, {"name": "fn", "size": 460}, {"name": "gt", "size": 603}, {"name": "gte", "size": 625}, {"name": "iff", "size": 748}, {"name": "isa", "size": 461}, {"name": "lt", "size": 597}, {"name": "lte", "size": 619}, {"name": "max", "size": 283}, {"name": "min", "size": 283}, {"name": "mod", "size": 591}, {"name": "mul", "size": 603}, {"name": "neq", "size": 599}, {"name": "not", "size": 386}, {"name": "or", "size": 323}, {"name": "orderby", "size": 307}, {"name": "range", "size": 772}, {"name": "select", "size": 296}, {"name": "stddev", "size": 363}, {"name": "sub", "size": 600}, {"name": "sum", "size": 280}, {"name": "update", "size": 307}, {"name": "variance", "size": 335}, {"name": "where", "size": 299}, {"name": "xor", "size": 354}, {"name": "_", "size": 264}]}, {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843}, {"name": "Not", "size": 1554}, {"name": "Or", "size": 970}, {"name": "Query", "size": 13896}, {"name": "Range", "size": 1594}, {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130}, {"name": "Sum", "size": 791}, {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124}, {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876}, {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}]}, {"name": "scale", "children": [{"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105}, {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316}, {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151}, {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770}, {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435}, {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839}, {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756}, {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268}, {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821}, {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}]}, {"name": "util", "children": [{"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258}, {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001}, {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217}, {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555}, {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324}, {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993}, {"name": "heap", "children": [{"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354}, {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}]}, {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335}, {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383}, {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874}, {"name": "math", "children": [{"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165}, {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815}, {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}]}, {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705}, {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486}, {"name": "palette", "children": [{"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367}, {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229}, {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059}, {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}]}, {"name": "Property", "size": 5559}, {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118}, {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887}, {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557}, {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}]}, {"name": "vis", "children": [{"name": "axis", "children": [{"name": "Axes", "size": 1302}, {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593}, {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652}, {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636}, {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}]}, {"name": "controls", "children": [{"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138}, {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824}, {"name": "Control", "size": 1353}, {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665}, {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649}, {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832}, {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896}, {"name": "IControl", "size": 763}, {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222}, {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862}, {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}]}, {"name": "data", "children": [{"name": "Data", "size": 20544}, {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788}, {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349}, {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301}, {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382}, {"name": "render", "children": [{"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698}, {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569}, {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353}, {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}]}, {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275}, {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147}, {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}]}, {"name": "events", "children": [{"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313}, {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880}, {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701}, {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}]}, {"name": "legend", "children": [{"name": "Legend", "size": 20859}, {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614}, {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}]}, {"name": "operator", "children": [{"name": "distortion", "children": [{"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461}, {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314}, {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}]}, {"name": "encoder", "children": [{"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179}, {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060}, {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138}, {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690}, {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}]}, {"name": "filter", "children": [{"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219}, {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165}, {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}]}, {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286}, {"name": "label", "children": [{"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956}, {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899}, {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}]}, {"name": "layout", "children": [{"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725}, {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727}, {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317}, {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003}, {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853}, {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411}, {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864}, {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174}, {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881}, {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870}, {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728}, {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348}, {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870}, {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121}, {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}]}, {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490}, {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248}, {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190}, {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581}, {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}]}, {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}]}]}';



  console.log(flareStr)
  flare=JSON.parse(flareStr);
  console.log(flare);

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function parse_data(flare)
  {
  console.log("in Parse_data")


  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

      function collapse(d) {
        console.log("in collapse")
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
  }

parse_data(flare);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

I entered the data as a JSON string - To generate this I used Python

```
import json
with open("flare.json","r") as ifp:
    jd=json.load(ifp)

#JD is a python type of dictionary now
type(jd)

#I would like a JSON_STRING However
jstr=json.dumps(jd)
```

I then extracted the jstr data and put it in a **var**, which  is the line starting  *var flareStr='{"name": "flare", "children": [{"name":*

The *console.log(flareStr)* allows me to see what is going on into the web-page - go to your web-browser (firefox is my choice) and look at source...

Next I parse the string to make it a proper JSON object...

```
flare=JSON.parse(flareStr);
```

And as I am not using the d3.json method, I created my own function (note: I have no idea if a variable is local or global in js... so you may need to clear this up).

The method to parse the data was taken from the original code -

```
function parse_data(flare)
  {
  console.log("in Parse_data")


  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

      function collapse(d) {
        console.log("in collapse")
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
  }
```

which is then simply called via

```
parse_data(flare);
```

I hope this assists someone else.