# d3.js flare.json using my created Json w/ collapsible tree

Tags: json, d3.js

I created my own Json file to use with the [collapsible tree in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).  I have three extra fields in the file for each child.  I created one for one root node that has three children.  Each of those children have leaves, and ends there, so a total of three levels.

I am stuck as being able to load the json.  I have ran the code with the original flare.json, so all else is working.  I have the same json pasted below.    Thank you!

UPDATE: I was able to deal with this by copy/pasting the json into the html to create a variable as in this question: [How to load data from an internal JSON array rather than from an external resource / file for a collapsible tree in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940854/how-to-load-data-from-an-internal-json-array-rather-than-from-an-external-resour/23164907#23164907)  It works, though not ideal as I have a large json list.

Here is a pastebin link of my html code: http://pastebin.com/njdfrwhf  Thanks!

```
  {
"name": "checkD",
"children": [
     {
     "name": "XX.YY.IP1",
     "children": [
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.1", "distance": 1, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.2", "distance": 1.8, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.3", "distance": 4.5, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.4", "distance": 2.5, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.5", "distance": 1, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.6", "distance": 2, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.7", "distance": 1, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.8", "distance": 3, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.9", "distance": 1, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.10", "distance": 5, "CC": "US", "m":1}
      ]
    },
     {
     "name": "XX.YY.IP2",
     "children": [
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.1", "distance": 1, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.2", "distance": 1.8, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.3", "distance": 2, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.4", "distance": 4.3, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.5", "distance": 5, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.6", "distance": 2, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.7", "distance": 1.3, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.8", "distance": 3, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.9", "distance": 4, "CC": "US", "m":1},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.10", "distance": .5, "CC": "US", "m":1}
      ]
     },
     {
     "name": "XX.YY.IP3",
     "children": [
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.1", "distance": 1, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.2", "distance": 1.8, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.3", "distance": 2, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.4", "distance": 4.3, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.5", "distance": 5, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.6", "distance": 2, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.7", "distance": 1.3, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.8", "distance": 3, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.9", "distance": 4, "CC": "US", "m":0},
      {"name": "xxx.yyy.10", "distance": .5, "CC": "US", "m":0}
      ]
     }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Problem you are facing is that you are not able to load the json file from your server?

Comment: That could be a reason.  I inititally tried loading the file by using the file name only ("test3.json") (its in the same directory as the html file), then secondly by using the full http: "localhost:8888/test3.json"  I assume it is not a file format issue, I made sure it is pure text, and the format of the {[: etc.. are all fine as a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load a file with d3.json, it uses an http request. If the file is local, most modern browsers will refuse to GET the file, because that would be a security risk to users of their browsers (GET c:\allmypasswords.txt)

Firefox is more permissive with requesting local files from locally run HTML, so you can try running your code there. The alternative is to serve the JSON file with a server, either by hosting it on the web or running a server locally.

**EDIT** It seems the issue is actually the JSON. You have two values that contain leading decimals. When I added a 0 in front of the decimal it worked. Weird.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am running a server `code` python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888 & `code`  Then put the URL in my browser: http://localhost:8888/file.html  I changed loading the file from test.json to: d3.json("http://localhost:8888/test3.json", function(error, flare) { but I am still getting the same error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'root.x0 = height / 2').  But when I revert back to using the local variable w/ the json contents, it works.  I put the code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/njdfrwhf  Thanks for your help

Comment: I think the issue might be the JSON file itself, I've edited my answer above.

Comment: thanks a lot, that made it finally work!  I tested and could also read the file in locally (but running the python http server)