# D3.js JSON parse error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

While parsing inline JSON object with `d3.json(obj, function(error, root)`, its working properly when I'm running it locally, but when I run on tomcat server I'm getting an XMLHttpparse error. I searched over the Internet. Answer that I found was CORS. But there was no clarity how to achieve this. Could you please help me?

```
var obj = {
 "name": "vis",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "Votes",
   "children": [
    {"name": "200", "size": 200,"url":"1"},
    {"name": "500", "size": 500,"url":"2"},
    {"name": "300", "size": 300,"url":"3"},
    {"name": "400", "size": 400,"url":"4"}
   ]
  },  
  {
   "name": "Reputation", 
   "children": [
    {"name": "200", "size": 200},
    {"name": "500", "size": 500},
    {"name": "300", "size": 300},
    {"name": "400", "size": 400}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Accepted Answer",
   "children": [    
    {
     "name": "encoder",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Accepted Answer", "size": 500}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
};
d3.json(obj, function(error, root) {
    alert('error '+error);
    alert('root: '+root);
  if (error) return console.log(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `d3.json` is used for. `d3.json` makes an actual AJAX request (hence why in the documentation names the chapter as [Requests](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)) so it is literally trying to fetch that obj but can't because it doesn't need to. If you really want to use `d3.json`, you can move that JSON object into its own file and then reference it by doing `d3.json(data.json, function(err, root))`.

The result `d3.json` would return is literally the object you have declared. You can simply assign it to the variable name `root`.

Related question: [d3 js - loading json without a http get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934853/d3-js-loading-json-without-a-http-get)

Comment: Why would you need to `JSON.parse(obj)` if `obj` is already a JavaScript object?

Comment: @Oleg okay you probably don't need to do that. I removed that tidbit.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you are passing in a URL as the first argument to d3.json().

Second, you need to configure Tomcat to support CORS. In version 7.0.41+, Tomcat includes a CORS filter. Add the filter to your web.xml file.

Here's the minimum configuration you need:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

See the documentation for more information and additional configuration options: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

And here's a [flowchart](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png) of request processing for this filter that may help you with setting up any additional parameters:

[image: CORS flowchart]